# Visualizing data using CoMut

Tags: data-visualization, sequencing

My question is about visualizing mutations of cohort of samples, something exactly like coMut map (https://www.broadinstitute.org/blog/visualizing-cancer-genome).
Does someone know if there is a specific website for making these type of plots?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

here they are: some tools/R programms to plot

http://aaronmck.github.io/2014/08/04/Comut-plot-with-D3/

http://gdac.broadinstitute.org/runs/analyses__latest/reports/cancer/GBM-TP/MutSigNozzleReport2.0/nozzle.html

R
https://benchtobioinformatics.wordpress.com/2015/05/25/how-to-make-a-co-mutation-plot/

http://firebrowse.org/iCoMut/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It was helpful.